# Unexpected Token in discord.js node_modules/@discordjs/src/rest/APIRequest.js:34

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Full Error:

```
c:\Users\beed\.vscode\HTML + JS\Javascript\Mystic-Sneaky_Helper_2\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\APIRequest.js:34
    agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\beed\.vscode\HTML + JS\Javascript\Mystic-Sneaky_Helper_2\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RESTManager.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.117 seconds
```

I used VSCode, I followed the DisordJS Guide, I used `Code Runner` to run the JavaScript.

==== DIVIDER ====

Directory:

- commands
- ping.js
- node_modules
- @discord.js

  - rest

    - APIRequest.js

  Some More Modules...

  **NOTE: I ONLY SHOWED THE MODULE THE ERROR IS IN.**
- config.json
- deploy_commands.js
- index.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json

It took me some time to write the directory above, so please answer...

Index.js:

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json')
const fs = require('fs')

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.commands = new Collection()

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

==== DIVIDER ====

Thanks in advance,

Beedful

Comment: I think this error `Unexpected token '??='` saying that you need to add `engines` in `package.json`.

Comment: @新Acesyyy, thanks for your comment, but how do I add it? Please do answer.

Comment: Alright, I added the engines module but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you edit your post by adding your actual codes?

Comment: Will do. I will edit it.

Comment: Where'd you get your token? in developers? It seems you mistype the token.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to Node.JS v15.0.0+

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's in `^16.10.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is `Unexpected token '??='`, you should try to add `engines` in your `package.json`

```
"engines": {
  "node": "16.x"
}
```

let me know if it works.